# Android Beam json file

Tags: android, json, nfc, android-json, android-beam

I have a simple activity that launches a file chooser and then sends the file via Android beam like so:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data) {
    if (requestCode==0 && resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
        adapter.setBeamPushUris(new Uri[] {data.getData()}, this);
        Button btn=new Button(this);
        btn.setText("Done");
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        setContentView(btn);
    }
}
```

The activity is able to correctly beam 
images and .txt files. However, I get "Beam did not complete" when I beam .json files.

I thought it was because, there's no application on the receiver that views json files, so I created another version with to view received txt files. The manifest has

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

When I change the extension of my json files to .txt, the file is sent correctly and the receiving application gets launched. But when I change the extension back to .json and the mimetype of the receiver to "application/json", I still get the "Beam did not complete" message.

Any ideas why?

Thanks!

Comment: Curious... what does the URI to the JSON file look like?

Comment: @unrulygnu - the uri is: file:///storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.test.nfctest/files/test.json

Comment: I dont think there are any apps that explicitly state they accept JSON files. You should probably just send them as text. You can probably keep the .json, just make sure the mimetype is `text/*`

Comment: @kentarosu - when I view the properties of the .json files using a file explorer, I don't see any mimetype. How can I ensure that the json files have the text/* mimetype

Comment: I'm almost sure all `.json` files are merely `.txt` files with a different extension on the end. That's it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Any ideas why?

[Android Beam](https://developer.android.com/training/beam-files/index.html) uses the file extension of **the first file in the Beam `Uri`s array** to look up a corresponding MIME type in an internal map, which is then sent with the [`Intent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) that initiates the file transfer via Bluetooth Object Push Profile (OPP).

If the file extension or a matching MIME type is not found, the [`Intent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)'s MIME type is set to `null`, and the Bluetooth OPP file transfer isn't initiated at all.

**WORKAROUND**

When sending a file with an extension that is not listed in [`MimeUtils`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-5.0.2_r1/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/MimeUtils.java), use a two-element Beam [`Uri`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html)s array:

`uris[0]`:  a dummy text file with a `.txt` extension, (to be deleted later)
`uris[1]`:  the file (with the unrecognized extension) which you want to transfer

In your specific case:

```
        adapter.setBeamPushUris(
                new Uri[] { dummyTxtFileUri, data.getData() },
                this);
```

Android Beam will send an intent to Bluetooth with a MIME type of `text/plain`, along with the [`Uri`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html)s for both files, and the Bluetooth OPP file transfer will occur normally.  Note that when beaming multiple files at once, the receiving device will store the files in a subdirectory in `beam/`, usually named `beam-YYYY-MM-DD/`.

**BACKGROUND**

I compared the logs on the sending device between sending a file with a `.json` extension, and a copy of that file with a `.txt` extension.  The first notable difference is here:

log: beaming **`test.json`**

```
03-02 13:19:34.665: D/BluetoothOppHandover(32332): Handing off outging transfer to BT
```

log: beaming **`test.txt`**

```
03-02 15:32:19.437: D/BluetoothOppHandover(3268): Handing off outging transfer to BT
03-02 15:32:19.445: D/BluetoothOppUtility(3309): putSendFileInfo: uri=file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/test.txt@2cb672fa sendFileInfo=com.android.bluetooth.opp.BluetoothOppSendFileInfo@2cb672fa
```

Searching AOSP for "Handing off outging transfer to BT":

[platform/packages/apps/Nfc/src/com/android/nfc/handover/BluetoothOppHandover.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Nfc/+/android-5.0.2_r1/src/com/android/nfc/handover/BluetoothOppHandover.java)

```
void sendIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setPackage("com.android.bluetooth");
    String mimeType = MimeTypeUtil.getMimeTypeForUri(mContext, mUris[0]);
    intent.setType(mimeType);
    // ...
    if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "Handing off outging transfer to BT");
    mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);

    complete();
}
```

Before moving on, note that MIME type for **only the first `Uri` in the array** is sent in the `Intent`.  Following `MimeTypeUtil.getMimeTypeForUri()`:

[platform/packages/apps/Nfc/src/com/android/nfc/handover/MimeTypeUtil.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Nfc/+/android-5.0.2_r1/src/com/android/nfc/handover/MimeTypeUtil.java)

```
    public static String getMimeTypeForUri(Context context, Uri uri) {
        // ...
            String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(uri.getPath()).toLowerCase();
            if (extension != null) {
                return MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        // ...
```

So if it doesn't identify an extension, it returns `null` as the MIME type.  Following `MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension()`...

[frameworks/base/core/java/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.0.2_r1/core/java/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.java)

```
    public String getMimeTypeFromExtension(String extension) {
        return MimeUtils.guessMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    }
```

[platform/libcore/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/MimeUtils.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-5.0.2_r1/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/MimeUtils.java)

```
public final class MimeUtils {
    private static final Map<String, String> mimeTypeToExtensionMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    private static final Map<String, String> extensionToMimeTypeMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // ...

    public static String guessMimeTypeFromExtension(String extension) {
        if (extension == null || extension.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return extensionToMimeTypeMap.get(extension);
    }
```

Before moving on, note that this [`MimeUtils` class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-5.0.2_r1/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/MimeUtils.java) contains the list of MIME types that are recognized by Android.  It's a good reference.

We've reached the end of the stack with `extensionToMimeTypeMap.get()`:

[platform/libcore/luni/src/main/java/java/util/HashMap.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore.git/+/android-5.0.2_r1/luni/src/main/java/java/util/HashMap.java)

```
    /**
     * Returns the value of the mapping with the specified key.
     *
     * @param key
     *            the key.
     * @return the value of the mapping with the specified key, or {@code null}
     *         if no mapping for the specified key is found.
    */
    public V get(Object key) {
```

So if no match is found, the MIME type is ultimately returned as `null`.  A bit more digging shows where this matters:

[platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/src/com/android/bluetooth/opp/BluetoothOppHandoverReceiver.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/android-5.0.2_r1/src/com/android/bluetooth/opp/BluetoothOppHandoverReceiver.java)

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // ...
        if (action.equals(Constants.ACTION_HANDOVER_SEND)) {
            String type = intent.getType();
            Uri stream = (Uri)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
            if (stream != null && type != null) {
                // Save type/stream, will be used when adding transfer
                // session to DB.
            BluetoothOppManager.getInstance(context).saveSendingFileInfo(type,
                    stream.toString(), true);
            } else {
                if (D) Log.d(TAG, "No mimeType or stream attached to handover request");
            }
        // ...
        // we already know where to send to
        BluetoothOppManager.getInstance(context).startTransfer(device);
```

Since there is a null check on the MIME type before saving the file info and starting the transfer, the Bluetooth OPP file transfer never initiates.  Note that the other two conditional blocks `return` when there is a `null`, so it seems the fact that this one is missing a `return` after the `Log.d()` call may be a bug.